# Include scss in vuejs components npm package conditionally, based on conditions set in the project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to create css/scss themes for my Vue Components Npm package. It's a local package which I am testing with `npm link`

Both Package and Project are using webpack.

**index.js of Package**

```
import "./src/sass/main.scss";
import "./src/sass/theme_a.scss"; // This needs to be inculded based on options

install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$package = Vue.observable({ options });
    Vue.component("a-button", a_button);
    --- more ---
}
```

**index.js of the Project**

```
import Package from 'package'

Vue.use(Package, {
    theme: 'theme_a',
    style: 'style_a'
    --- more ---
});

new Vue({el: '#app',   render: h => h(App)});
```

What I want to achieve is to include specific scss theme files in index.js of Package, while set the theme for the project in index.js of the Project, in the `Vue.use()` function.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to include the sass css code only if your button condition is true?

As a SPA this CSS code will be sent to the browser, why not just wrap with a parent class in your template?

```html
<template>
  <div :class="{ style-a: isStyleA }">
  ...[your button html]
  </div>
</template>
<script>
...[component script]
</script>
<style lang="scss">
.style-a {
   ...[your button component styles]
}
</style>
```

Comment: I want to serve only those css which correspond to the required theme, that way I can keep the css lean. Keeping the styles in a scss file instead of in component file will mean that I won't have to copy the same code for each component. I can simply add the required css class and scss file will handle the rest.